# Weird ImageButton's behavior on ListView

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, imagebutton

ImageButtons on a ListView is giving me a headache. **[Take a look at the gif here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwKP9.gif)**

As you can see, the ImageButtons (3 vertical dots on the right of every ListView row) which were hidden gets super small as the ListView is scrolled up and down.

**This is the corresponding XAML:**

```
<ImageButton
    Source="more_options"
    HorizontalOptions="End"
    WidthRequest="21"
    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
    Clicked="OnMoreOptionsTapped"
    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
    Grid.Column="2"
    Grid.Row="0"/>
```

**[Full XAML is here.](https://pastebin.com/YDyhWCgm)** ImageButton is at line 56.

I'm doing something wrong? How can I fix this?

---

Also, I know I could use just an Image with a TapGestureRecognizer but that's being a big issue for me, because I need access to the Image element to get it's coordinates and spawn the menu on the right location. Doing that with an ImageButton is a piece of cake, but it's not so easy with a TapGestureRecognizer. I did something like this:

**XAML**

```
<Image
    Source="more_options"
    Aspect="AspectFit"
    HorizontalOptions="End"
    WidthRequest="21"
    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
    Grid.Column="2"
    Grid.Row="0">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer 
            Tapped="OnMoreOptionsTapped"
            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
private void OnMoreOptionsTapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs args)
{
    var tapGesture = sender as TapGestureRecognizer;
    var button = tapGesture.Parent as Image;
    ...
}
```

Basically, with an ImageButton element, the `object sender` is an ImageButton element, but with an Image, the `object sender` is a TapGestureRecognizer and I can't find a way to get the Image parent while I have only the TapGestureRecognizer child. Also, `tapGesture.Parent` is null and `tapGesture.Parent.Parent` is null too. I've tried both.

---

**So:**

1. ImageButtons on ListView are bugging out hard. Anyone have a fix?
2. Anyone could tell me how to get the Image parent having only the child TapGestureRecognizer?

I believe answering any of those two questions would solve my problem hehe.

Also, this is one of my first experiences asking questions here, I beg your pardon if I did something wrong.

Thanks all :)

Comment: Dio you have a ListView and Xamarin Forms v3.5?

Comment: @G.hakim yes. I even tried the beta 4.0 and it's still bugged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind your issue is a bug that is currently in the xamarin listview which can be found here :

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5200

Solution is to downgrade to v3.4 for now until we get an intimate from XF side

Goodluck revert if you have queries

Comment: Thanks for the input, but reverting didn't work. I've downgraded to first and last 3.4 versions but no luck whatsoever. ImageButton's behavior was the same. There's a PR to fix this issue https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/5233 - hope it gets through asap hehe

Comment: Did you delete the application before rerunning it? Shared runtime can be pesky at times always delete the existing build and re-run the code after changing XF version

Comment: I didn't but as soon as I saw your comment I tried again (deleting the app this time) and it didn't work either

Comment: @agharium you mind if I log this bug on GitHub? We might receive a better solution from there